# Setting input type in EditTextView programmatically makes the cursor go back to the start of EditTextView

Tags: android, android-edittext

When the user typed # in EditTextView I set its input type to 
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD. By doing that the effect was the cursor is going back to the start of the EditTextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add something like the following after setting the input type

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
```

I know It's not exactly ideal but I'm pretty sure it's the only way to get the behavior you want.

Comment: So it's the behavior of edittext if you change the input type programatically.

Comment: I believe it's if you change anything about the editable content of the EditText it goes back to the beginning in terms of the cursor.  I think it's more about if something in the content changes then you should figure out where the cursor goes and they decided it should go to the beginning by default. Personally I think it should be a the end not the beginning but I didn't get a vote on that one ;)